# there + (modal) + passive

Tags: passive-voice, modal-verbs, there-is

What's your opinion on using "*there + (modal) + passive*"? Is it natural? There are a lot of such examples in scholar.google.com (for example "[there should be used](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22there%20should%20be%20used%22&btnG=)", "[there can be distinguished](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22there%20can%20be%20distinguished%22&btnG=)" or "[there is applied](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22there%20is%20applied%22&btnG=)").

> [businessdocbox.com](https://businessdocbox.com/Marketing/71292635-University-of-zilina-transcom-th-european-conference-of-young-research-and-scientific-workers-proceedings-section-2.html):
>
> **1.** **There should be used** arguments and facts.
>
> [upol.cz](https://mefanet.upol.cz/BP/2005/2/221.pdf):
>
> **2.** **There can be distinguished** 3 types of layer – an input,
>   hidden and output layer.
>
> [justia.com](https://patents.justia.com/patent/4735172):
>
> **3.** Between the nipples 84 and 85 **there is applied** a tube 86 connecting these two nipples.

Thanks!

Comment: An expression like “ There can be distinguished 3 types of layer – an input, hidden and output layer.” sounds needlessly heavy and cumbersome. You could just as easily say “There are three types of layer: input, hidden, and output.”. Unless you have some pedant as an editor or reviewer, simpler writing will increase the likelihood of your paper being read.

Comment: Some of these meet the conditions for [_There_-insertion](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+there+insertion) and others don't. That's what determines grammaticality. "There plus modal plus passive" is not a construction, nor even a constituent.